# Jquery: ajax loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a page which tells me on which page of youtube search results my video is ranked. I am using AJAX.

I have this is in my php page

```
<?php
$search_term = "Search Term";
$page_link = "rbdSxr9Vvw0"; //this is the youtube video id
$search_term = str_replace(" ","+",$search_term);
$youtube_search = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=".$search_term."&";
$i = $_POST['i'];
if(strpos(file_get_contents($youtube_search."page=$i"),$page_link) == false){
echo "not found";
}else{
echo "found";
}
?>
```

I need to write jquery function which will send numbers starting from 1 to the php page. It needs to show the current page it's checking and the result. It needs to stop when the result says "found". Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I ended up using this code:

In my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "../jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function checkPage(i){
    console.log("checking page", i);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {page: i},
        success: function(data){
            if(data != "found"){
                $('#div').text("not found at "+i);;
                checkPage(i+1);
            }
            else {
                alert("found at page "+i);
            }
        }
    });
}

checkPage(1);
</script>

</body>
<div id = "div"></div>
</html>
```

In my ajax page:

```
<?php
$search_term = "search term";
$page_link = "ZXsdlk0_HuQ"; //this is the youtube video id
$search_term = str_replace(" ","+",$search_term);
$youtube_search = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=".$search_term."&";
$result = "false";
$i = $_GET['page'];
if(strpos(file_get_contents($youtube_search."page=$i"),$page_link) == false){
echo "not found";
}else{
echo "found";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something for the client side? It looks like you just need a very basic $.ajax.

Comment: @briosheje I have tried using the while loop. it works. But it doesn't show the current page it's checking. It goes on until the video is found and then shows the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. You'd have to receive the "page" in your PHP, but this would work.

```
function checkPage(i){
    console.log("checking page", i);
    $.ajax({
        url: "myPHPPageURL",
        data: {page: i},
        success: function(data){
            if(data != "found"){
                checkPage(i+1);
            }
            else {
                alert("found at page "+i);
            }
        }
    });
}

checkPage(1);
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I made some changes and it works awesome!

Answer (score 1):

```
var loop_end = SMTH;

for (var i = 0; i < loop_end; i++) {
   $.ajax({
     url: '/path/to/script.php',
     type: "POST",
     data: {i: i},
     success: function (data) {
     }
  });
}
```